# why the browser doesn't show the date on page but download the date as files?

Tags: apache2, xmlhttprequest, cgi

I use xmlhttprequest to "get" one part of data on the server, instead of showing the data on browser, the browser let me to download it and it tells me it's a PL file. 
Then I try to get some other data in the same way. The browser shows them well. I change the content-type to application/octet-stream and download the data which can be shown on the borwser, it tells me it's a SSR source file. I dont know why this happened?

Comment: Is Apache set up to handle .pl files as a cgi script in the directory you are using? Also, what browsers have you tried?

Comment: I've set that and with the same script some other data can be displayed on the browser well. I tried IE,Chrome and Firefox. I got the same thing.

Comment: What types of data are you trying to display? What is the difference between succeding and failing requests? Also, what mimetypes seem to work with what data? How do you request different datasets (urls...)? What does your javascript do with the result of the request? Guesses turn educated guesses once I know enough.